# How do I retrieve available languages for creating a site using CSOM

Tags: csom

When creating a new SharPoint Online web using CSOM .Net, I have to provide a valid LCID for Language property in WebCreationInformation object (when not using default). Is there a way of retrieving a list valid LCIDs from the server or do I have to hard-code this list in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. May be it can help you

```
  SPLanguageCollection lang = SPRegionalSettings.GlobalInstalledLanguages;

  foreach (SPLanguage language in lang)
  {
         Console.WriteLine(format, language.LCID, language.DisplayName);
  }
```

Ref: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.language(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: He wants CSOM not SSOM.